# Calculate difference of multiple inputs and write on page

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue calculating the difference of two variables that should change depending on input values and number of inputs.

The jQuery works fine adding/subtracting buttons it's the peoplePaid() function that I've been dealing with.

I'm trying to write the difference (.difference) of paidTotal minus each input of pCheck.

So the first question is how do I get the value for difference (paidTotal - pCheck) to write to .difference for each input on the page.

And if I have to loop iy what may need to be done.

Thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var maxFields = 20;
    var addButton = $('#plusOne');
    var deleteButton = $('#minusOne');
    var wrapper = $('#userNumbers');
    var fieldInput = '<div><input type="text" name="persons" class="persons"/></div>';
    var x = 1;

    $(addButton).click(function () {
        if (x < maxFields) {
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append(fieldInput);
        }

    });

    $(deleteButton).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var myNode = document.getElementById("userNumbers");
        i = myNode.childNodes.length - 1;
        if (i >= 0) {
            myNode.removeChild(myNode.childNodes[i]);
            x--;
        }

    });

});

function peoplePaid() {
  var checkTotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById('check').value);
  var personsCheck = document.getElementsByClassName('persons');
  var paidTotal = document.getElementById('paidTotal');
  var serviceQuality = document.getElementById('serviceQuality').value;
  var difference = document.getElementsByClassName('difference');

  var pCheck = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < personsCheck.length; i += 1) {
    pCheck += parseFloat(personsCheck[i].value);

  }
  paidTotal.innerHTML = (checkTotal * serviceQuality) - pCheck;

  for (var i = 0; i < personsCheck.length; i += 1) {

    checkDifference = parseFloat(paidTotal - pCheck).value;
  }



}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Check Total</h3>
$ <input type="text" id="check" value="" />

<h3>Tip%</h3>
<select name="tip" id="serviceQuality">
  <option disabled selected value="1">-- Choose an Option --</option>

  <option value="1">0%</option>
  <option value="1.06">6%</option>
  <option value="1.15">15%</option>
  <option value="1.2">20%</option>
  <option value="1.3">30%</option>
</select>

<h3>Number of People: <span id="numberOfPeople"></span></h3>

<button type="button" onclick="plusOne()" id="plusOne">+</button>
<button type="button" onclick="minusOne()" id="minusOne">-</button>


<div>
  <div id="userNumbers">
    <input type="text" class="persons" name="person" />
    <p class="difference">$</p>
  </div>
</div>


<button onclick="peoplePaid()">Calculate</button>
<!--Paid Amount-->
<div>
  <h3>Paid Amount: <span id="paidTotal"></span></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: The difference between `paidTotal - pCheck`? Is `pCheck` an accumulation of what? Are the plus and minus buttons supposed to add/remove inputs that have arbitrary amounts? The functions that add/remove the inputs do not work.

Answer (score 0):

## Disscrepancies

There were some discrepancies that should be addressed:

1. (Major) There are two functions called by onclick event handlers:

   ```
   <button type="button" onclick="plusOne()" id="plusOne">+</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="minusOne()" id="minusOne">-</button>
   ```

   First of all, a quick run of this Snippet logs errors about these functions not existing. Secondly, you should never use on-event handlers when using jQuery, it's like using paddle (on-event handlers) on a speed boat (event delegation using `.on()`).
2. (Minor) If you store jQuery Objects in variables, do not wrap those variables in `$(...)` because they already wrapped in `$(...)` when you declared them:

   ```
   var addButton = $('#plusOne');

   $(addButton).on('click',... // That is like doing this: $($('#plusOne'))
   addButton.on('click',...... // This is the cleaner way or...

   var $addButton = $('#plusOne');

   $addButton.on('click'...... /* This is a common practice which serves as an obvious 
   reminder that the variable is a jQuery Object */
   ```

---

### Plain JavaScript Array Methods

1. (Core) The solution is to collect all of the `input.customer'` by gathering the `<input>s` into a NodeList with `.querySelctorAll()` and then converting it into an array with `Array.from()`:

   ```
   var customers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.customer'));
   ```
2. Next, use `.map()` to extract each of the `<input>'s` values, and then return them as an array:

   ```
   var payments = customers.map(function(customer) {
     return parseFloat(customer.value);
   });
   ```
3. Finally, use `.reduce()` to add all of the values in the `payments` array into one number:

   ```
   paidTotal = payments.reduce(function(total, number) {
     return total + number;
   });
   ```

---

### Demo

```js
var max = 20;
var count = 1;
var paidTotal = 0;
var customerQty = $('#totalCustomers');
var add = $('#add');
var group = $('.group');
var paid = `
<li>
<input type="number" class="customer" step='0.01'/>
<button type="button" class="remove">-</button>
</li>`;

add.on('click', function(e) {
  if (count < max) {
    count++;
    group.append(paid);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  customerQty.val(count);
});

group.on('click', '.remove', function() {
  if (count > 0) {
    count--;

    var subtract = parseFloat($(this).prev('.customer').val()).toFixed(2);
    var total = parseFloat($('#paidTotal').val()).toFixed(2);
    var newTotal = parseFloat(total - subtract).toFixed(2);
    $('#paidTotal').val(newTotal);

    var due = parseFloat($('#balanceDue').val());
    $('#balanceDue').val((due + parseFloat(subtract)).toFixed(2));

    $(this).parent().remove();

  } else {
    return false;
  }
  customerQty.val(count);
});

$('#bill').on('input', totalPaid);

function totalPaid(e) {
  var check = $('#check').val();
  var tip = $('#tip').val();
  var total = $('#paidTotal');
  var due = $('#balanceDue');

  var customers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.customer'));

  var payments = customers.map(function(customer) {
    return parseFloat(customer.value);
  });
  //console.log('payments: '+payments);
  paidTotal = payments.reduce(function(total, number) {
    return total + number;
  });

  $('#amountDue').val(parseFloat(check * tip).toFixed(2));

  //console.log('paidTotal: '+paidTotal);
  total.val(parseFloat(paidTotal).toFixed(2));
  due.val(parseFloat((check * tip) - total.val()).toFixed(2));
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 400 16px/1.5 Consolas;
}

body {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

fieldset {
  width: 490px;
}

button,
label,
select,
input,
output {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

label {
  margin: 5px;
}

input {
  width: 12ex;
  text-align: center
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

output {
  margin-left: -5px;
}

#totalCustomers {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: blue;
}

#tip {
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.tip {
  margin-left: -2px;
}

.customers {
  height: fit-content;
  min-height: 60px;
}

.group {
  margin: -8% 10px auto -25px;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  width: 40%;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.group li {
  padding-left: 0.1em;
}

.add {
  transform: translate(105%, -15%);
}


/*
For debugging purposes only (Optional)
*/

.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-left: 50%;
  background: #000;
  color: lime;
}

.as-console-row.as-console-row {
  background: #000;
}

.as-console-row.as-console-row::after {
  content: '';
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<form id='bill'>

  <fieldset class='total'>

    <legend>Total Amount Due</legend>

    $ <input type="number" id="check" value="" step='0.01' min='0.00'>

    <label class='tip'>Tip%</label>
    <select id="tip">
      <option disabled selected value="">Pick</option>
      <option value="1">0%</option>
      <option value="1.06">6%</option>
      <option value="1.15">15%</option>
      <option value="1.2">20%</option>
      <option value="1.3">30%</option>
    </select>

    <label>Amount Due: $
      <output id="amountDue">0.00</output>
    </label>

  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class='customers'>

    <legend>Total Customers:
      <output id="totalCustomers">1</output>
    </legend>

    <label class='add'> Add a Customer 
      <button type="button" id="add">+</button>
    </label>

    <ol class='group'>
      <li>
        <input type="number" class="customer" step='0.01' min='0.00' />
        <button type="button" class="remove">-</button>
      </li>
    </ol>

  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class='grandTotal'>

    <legend>Total Balance</legend>

    <label>Paid Amount: $
      <output id="paidTotal">0.00</output>
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>Balance Due: $
      <output id="balanceDue">0.00</output>
    </label>

  </fieldset>

</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```